# Uncheck all OTHER checkboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<div class="formControls">
  <label for="gdpr0" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="email" id="gdpr0" onchange="GDPRcheck();" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">By email</label> 
  <label for="gdpr1" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="phone" id="gdpr1" onchange="GDPRcheck();" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">By phone</label> 
  <label for="gdpr2" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="post" id="gdpr2" onchange="GDPRcheck();" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">By post</label> 
  <label for="gdpr3" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="none" id="gdpr3" onchange="GDPRcheck();" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">None</label>
  <p class="formDescription">Please check all methods by which you are happy to be contacted.</p>
</div>
```

What I am looking for is the correct javascript to uncheck any/all other options if the "none" option is checked - to ensure people can't check none *and* another option. I was going to use a function called GDPRcheck() to do this.

Comment: Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass `this` in `GDPRcheck` function so that the clicked element can be referenced inside function then use `querySelectorAll` to get all the checkbox. Then, set a condition that will `uncheck` all the other checkbox except for the checkbox with `none` when it is `checked`

```js
function GDPRcheck(elem){
  if(elem.value === 'none'){
    document.querySelectorAll('[id^="gdpr"]').forEach(function(chkBox){
      if(elem.checked && chkBox.value !== 'none'){
        chkBox.checked = false;
      }
    });
  } else {
     var noneChkBox = document.getElementById('gdpr3');
     if(noneChkBox.checked){
        noneChkBox.checked = false;
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="formControls">
  <label for="gdpr0" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="email" id="gdpr0" onchange="GDPRcheck(this);" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">By email</label> 
  <label for="gdpr1" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="phone" id="gdpr1" onchange="GDPRcheck(this);" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">By phone</label> 
  <label for="gdpr2" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="post" id="gdpr2" onchange="GDPRcheck(this);" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">By post</label> 
  <label for="gdpr3" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form[gdpr][]" value="none" id="gdpr3" onchange="GDPRcheck(this);" class="gdpr-option rsform-checkbox">None</label>
  <p class="formDescription">Please check all methods by which you are happy to be contacted.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this works if I select other options *then* pick "none", however if I select "none", or it's already selected, it still allows me to choose one of the other options as well. Is there a way to get it to also uncheck "none" if any of the other options are selected? So they can *either* pick any from email, phone and mail OR none?